# Rolling an evolution back

Tags: playframework-2.0, revert, playframework-evolutions

This question might seem stupid, but I cannot find any instruction on how to roll back an evolution in Play 2.0. Google only finds pages which say that the "Downs" section of an evolution file is used for that and that's all. Any pointers or instructions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you see this doc ? http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Evolutions

Comment: Yes, I have read it, but it does not say a word about reverting an evolution, using the `Downs!` section. I might be missing something, but really, the only somewhat remotely relevant topic is touched in the last note paragraph, where it says "In developement mode however it is often simpler to simply trash your developement database and reapply all evolutions from the beginning.". Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The **Downs** part is mainly used to revert an Evolution when the script has changed. That is, you have a project with *2.sql* applied to the database and then, due to a merge, *2.sql* is modified in the source. Play will run **Downs** on the old version and then **Ups** on the new 2.sql to ensure the database is in sync with the codebase.

As far as I know there is no way to trigger **Downs** by itself, as the purpose of an Evolution is to prepare the database to work with your code, and applying just one **Downs** step would leave the application in an inconsistent state with many potential errors arising.

If you really need to revert something, that would be a new Evolution (3.sql) where **Ups** would do the changes required.

Comment: What is the purpose of `# --- !Downs` section in evolutions ?

Comment: "The Downs part is mainly used to revert an Evolution when the script has changed."

Answer (score 6):

For play 2.4.x, according to the play documentation, you just need to call `Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions(database)` after the test. See here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithDatabases