# Testing scala play evolution in 1.sql (Down)

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

I am trying to test scala play evolutions in Dev mode. The Up part in 1.sql works fine and all the necessary tables are created in DB. 
But I want to make sure that the Downs are also working from 1.sql. 
What is the best way to enforce this situation so that Downs in 1.sql will be executed when the application starts (or processes request in Dev mode)?
I already have the following in config.

```
# Enable evolutions for default database
evolutionplugin=enabled
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true
```

thanks.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/28688482/3841803

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to rollback the database every time? What?

Comment: Thanks @singhakash Post did not really answered the question. 
Let me try to explain one more time. I am doing curious/paranoid testing of my evolution from 1.sql , specifically Downs part. 
When I am testing the Up portion I can create an empty database see the new tables created as part of evolution execution. 
Now what do I need to do to check the execution of Down part. 
Note that (creating new table in Up and deleting that table in Down is the simple test I have)